# Add single element/single tag to XML structure with PHP Dom

Tags: php, dom

I try to add a single element/single tag without a closing tag to an XML structure with PHP Dom to get something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ndxml>
  <credentials>
    <identity>User</identity> 
    <password>Password</password>
    <language name="default" modifier="de"/>
  </credentials>
</ndxml>
```

Does anybody know which command I can use to get this?

Comment: What you mean with "without an closing tag" ?

Comment: i mean this single tag <language name="default" modifier="de"/>
the other tags are opened with this <identity> and closed with this </identity>

Comment: omg is <language name="default" modifier="de"/> a short spell for <language name="default" modifier="de"></language> ?

Comment: **/>** is merely the end of the **language** tag.  This is how you close a self-contained tag.

Comment: oh friends, i didnt knew that, so then sorry for that stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

```
$domDocument = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$rootNode = $domDocument->createElement('ndxml');
$credentials = $domDocument->createElement('credentials');
$credentials->appendChild(new \DOMElement('identity', 'User'));
$credentials->appendChild(new \DOMElement('password', 'Password'));
$language = $domDocument->createElement('language');
$language->setAttribute('name', 'default');
$language->setAttribute('modifier', 'de');
$credentials->appendChild($language);

$rootNode->appendChild($credentials);
$domDocument->appendChild($rootNode);

echo $domDocument->saveXML();
echo "\n\n";

echo $domDocument->saveXML(null, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

OUTPUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ndxml><credentials><identity>User</identity><password>Password</password><language name="default" modifier="de"/></credentials></ndxml>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ndxml><credentials><identity>User</identity><password>Password</password><language name="default" modifier="de"></language></credentials></ndxml>
```

Comment: omg is  <language name="default" modifier="de"/> a short spell for <language name="default" modifier="de"></language> ?

Comment: @FabianArcanum: yes

Comment: oh friends, i didnt knew that, so then sorry for that stupid question...